# How to handle router transition from Ember.js controller?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How should I handle transitioning to a different view after a successful save of a new Project object? If my validation passes, I want to commit the @transaction and transition to the Projects index view.

**Controller:**

```
DA.ProjectsController = Em.ArrayController.extend
  createProject: (project) ->
    @transaction = DA.store.transaction()
    p = @transaction.createRecord(DA.Project, project)
    validation_errors = p.validate()

    if validation_errors
      DA.displayError validation_errors
    else
      @transaction.commit()

      ### What should be here to transition the route/view? ###
      router.transitionTo('projects') # Like this?
      DA.get('router').send('projects') # This?
      ###################################################
```

**Router:**

```
DA.Router = Em.Router.create
  location: 'history'

  root: Em.Route.extend
    index: Em.Route.extend
      route: '/'
      redirectsTo: 'projects'

    projects: Em.Route.extend
      route: '/projects'
      index: Em.Route.extend
        router: '/'
      connectOutlets: (router) ->
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('projects', DA.Project.find())
      showProject: Em.Route.transitionTo('project')

    project: Em.Route.extend
      route: '/projects/:project_id'
      connectOutlets: (router, project) ->
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('project', project)

    newProject: Em.Route.extend
      route: '/projects/new'
      connectOutlets: (router) ->
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('projectsNew')

    doProjects: (router) ->
      router.transitionTo('projects')
    doProjectsNew: (router) ->
      router.transitionTo('newProject')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have figured out my own question, but I'd love to hear others' input if there's a more appropriate way of doing this. This is what I ended up with:

```
DA.ProjectsController = Em.ArrayController.extend    
  createProject: (project) ->
    @transaction = DA.store.transaction()
    p = @transaction.createRecord(DA.Project, project)
    validation_errors = p.validate()

    if validation_errors
      DA.displayError validation_errors
    else
      @transaction.commit()
      DA.get('router').transitionTo('projects')
```

Comment: I think it's good, but instead of accessing statically the router, you have the `target` property which represents it.